Virtuoso configuration file not presented
I'm learning to use Virtuoso Open-source Edition.
I followed this link to install Virtuoso-opensource-7 on Ubuntu 24.04:
$ sudo apt install virtuoso-opensource

The installation was just fine, but I cannot start the Virtuoso server by this command:
$ virtuoso-t -f

It reports the following error:
09:38:23 There is no configuration file virtuoso.ini

There are only six files in the path /var/lib/virtuoso-opensource-7/db:
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Nov 26 09:53 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root     4096 Nov 25 09:40 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 69206016 Nov 26 09:53 virtuoso.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       14 Nov 26 08:53 virtuoso.lck
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     6222 Nov 26 09:53 virtuoso.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        0 Nov 25 09:40 virtuoso.pxa
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2097152 Nov 26 08:53 virtuoso-temp.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      185 Nov 26 09:53 virtuoso.trx

virtuoso.ini is not presented in the above path.
All the installation instructions and discussions I found said that one can directly modify virtuoso.ini file, as if they have access to a presented file.
Did I miss anything during installation?
How can I fix it?

In the general case, Virtuoso automatically creates both a default INI file (virtuoso.ini) and an empty DB file (virtuoso.db) in the $pwd at launch, if they do not already exist.
I note that the documentation you followed says —

In accordance with Debian policy that services should start immediately after they've been installed, Ubuntu have created a default instance based on a configuration file located at /etc/virtuoso-opensource-6.1/virtuoso.ini; the database itself lives in /var/lib/virtuoso-opensource-6.1/db/ (a similar layout to MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc).

Obviously, this was written about v6.1, but I would expect (I don't run Ubuntu, so cannot quickly confirm) a similar path (/var/lib/virtuoso-opensource-7/virtuoso.ini) would lead you to the v7 INI file.
You may find answers like this faster for yourself, by using commands like find / -name virtuoso.ini or locate virtuoso.ini in your environment.
This will probably work to start your instance —
cd /var/lib/virtuoso-opensource-7
virtuoso-t -f -c ./virtuoso.ini


Really helpful! I've found virtuoso.ini in /etc/virtuoso-opensource-7/! Thx!
